# How to add new rows and columns to pad numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have an array of matrices all of different sizes/dimensions and I need to pad them all to the same size (805, 16866). Bellow is the code I'm currently using to do this but I believe it could be vectorised, however I am not sure how to do this.

```
x1 = np.zeros((805, 16866))

for i in range(x[0].shape[0]):
    for j in range(x[0].shape[1]):
        x1[i, j] = x[0][i, j]
```

Comment: You can use [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above example, `x1[:x[0].shape[0], :x[0].shape[1]] = x` should work

Answer (score 0):

There's the `numpy.pad` function [(docs)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) which does what you need.

The code you want is

```
x1 = np.zeros((805,16866))

for i in range(x.shape[0])
  x1[i,:]= np.pad(x[i,:],x1.shape[0],'constant',constant_values=0)
```